# Adding new attribute and using it in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've added a new column to my Supplier model of 'source' and 'source_other'. The form I've set up for new suppliers, however, isn't correctly taking this attribute and adding it to the model

The migration looks like:

```
class AddNewColumnToOwner < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     add_column :owners, :source, :string
     add_column :owners, :source_other, :string
  end
end
```

And I know the migration has worked because I can see in my rails console that owners do have source and source_other listed as attributes.

Then, I've added it to the new owner form views/owners/new.html.haml:

```
.field{style: 'padding-bottom:0px;' }
        = f.input :source, as: :select, collection: HOW_HEAR, label: 'How did you hear about us?', allow_blank: false
      .field#other_source_field
        = f.input :source_other, input_html: { class: 'text_field' }, label: 'If other please let us know where you heard about us'
```

However, when I fill out the form to add a new owner and select one of the source options, it's not storing this in the table. I know this because when I check Owner.last in my rails console, I can see that source is 'nil', even though I selected an option for source in the form dropdown options.

I must be missing something but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have forgotten to permit those additional fields' params in your controller.